# diskpart list volume does not show all volumes

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-server-2012, diskpart

I have 2 disks attached to `windows2012 R2` machine. I can see both disks from diskpart's `list disk` command and both of them are `Online`. One disk has 2 volumes for `boot` partition and for `system reserved`. The other disk has just primary partition. I can see all 3 volumes (2 from first disk and 1 from second) under `Disk Management` utility. But when I check `list volume` in diskpart, it shows just 2 volumes which are from first disks but it does not show the volume from second disk. What could be reason for it?

Comment: right click my computer and click manage, view the disk your trying to fix the issue with. make sure its in mbr format. make primary and assign a drive letter. it should then show up. hope it works.

Comment: Dan you post a picture of your disk management screen? Is the 2nd disk "online" to be able to get its status?

Comment: `diskpart` will NOT list the volumes' file systems it doesn't not recognize.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select another disk to see its volume. 
1. Select the disk via select disk command. 
2. And then list volume command.

This will show up the available volumes on that disk.

Comment: Sorry it did not work. It still shows volumes of first disk only.

Comment: Have you selected other disk by using select disk <diskNumber>. And the list vol command.

Comment: yes I did that. In my case, I am looking for a disk whose disknumber is 1. so after `select disk 1`, it says `Disk 1 is now the selected disk`. But `list volume` shows volumes of disk 0 only.

Comment: @Rohanil I have the same problem. Does not matter if disk 0 or 1 is selected, volumes from ,disk 0 will always be shown by ```list vol```. Have you found a solution?